# Sharepoint Online O365 best practice

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, active-directory, infrastructure

Is there a place or community where it is possible to find knowledge about O365 and SharePoint Online, and how to setup an large organization up to using this.

My main concerns are the infrastructure, the structure of the AD and all the new "cloud" terms, so far I only have worked with 2010 and 2013 on-premis.

I really would like to do some preparation work and to gain knowledge on O365 and its SharePoint integration.

Do MS have some best practices? For On-prem it was super easy to find good documentation and guidelines on how to build an environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. You should turn your browser to FastTrack which does exactly what your asking for - all in one place: https://fasttrack.microsoft.com/office

If you have more that 150 users, Fast Track is for free.